# Problems in developing a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I created a .env file besides main.py, and I thought if I ran main.py, it would connect .env file, and my bot could be alive. However, it still didn’t work.

**This is my code:**

```
import discord
import os


client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have loggined in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('/hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

**and I got the error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python_work\main.py", line 19, in 
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
asyncio.run(runner())
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
return runner.run(main)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 777, in start
await self.login(token)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 609, in login
raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.**class**.**name**} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead
PS C:\Users\User>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post sceeenshots of your code. Take a [tour]. How did you set your token?

Comment: Python out of the box doesn’t use .env files, unless you include code which reads it explicitly.

Comment: Use something like [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to load environment variables from .env file. Python doesn't read variables from the file directly; they need to be set as environment variables.

Comment: @doneforaiur I put my token in the .env file, and it's like this:                                                         TOKEN = XOXOXOXOX

Answer (score 1):

The error is returning None so the token variable isn't being fetched properly. Adding this before client creating line should fix it.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

You will need to install Python-Dotenv if it is not already installed: pip install python-dotenv

Comment: I got the same error after adding this: TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__.__name__} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead
PS C:\Users\User>